# Xcode 11 presenting view controller visible through modally presented navigation controller

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode11

I have several views that are presented modally. Using iOS 13 & Xcode 11 (b7), for the ones where I have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller, the presenting view controller is visible between the navigation bar & the view navigation controller stack. Don't have this problem with Xcode 10 & iOS 12.

[image: Gap between nav bar & content view]

Does anyone know why this is happening & how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this wound up being pretty easy. All I needed to do was add an explicit background color to the Navigation Controller's Navigation Bar in my storyboard.

[image: Navigation Bar Background Color]

In Xcode 11, the "default" color for the background is now a black box with a red line through it, whereas in previous versions it was a white box with a red line. I mistakenly took this color to mean that I had previously set a color there when I in fact had not.